# SQL/ETL Error, VISION: Too many columns (how to allow > 256)

Tags: sql, pentaho, sql-server-2012

I perform an ETL and download about 100 tables to my Companies data warehouse to perform reports and analysis on. Unfortunately I have no say on the database design and practices of the company I am downloading this information from. I connect to the DB I download the data from with a jdbc:vortex:// URL. I download it to my MS SQL Server 2012 Warehouse.

Having said that, a critical table I need has over 400 columns. I can use DBVisualizer Free to query their data but when I query this table I get the error:

[Error Code: -1, SQL State: 07000]  dbFetch exception: VISION: Too many columns 408 (max: 256)

I also get this same error when I use Pentaho Kettle (Data Integration Services) to try to download this table into my warehouse.

I get this error even if I try to only grab a couple of columns from the table. I figure there has to be a way to allow pentaho and db visualizer to increase the number of columns but I can't find this information ANYWHERE. Most people aren't stupid enough to have more than 256 columns in a table so I am having a very difficult time finding a solution for this problem.

Comment: possible solution - create 2 views of that big table - each with about half the columns... then query those.

Comment: is you're using SQL Server, why not use SSIS?

Comment: I can't use SSIS because I use a JDBC connection to gather the data. SSIS Does not support this. I also can't create 2 views because first I have to actually get the data before I can create views against it. The problem here is I can't download the source table (which is beyond my control to edit. All I can do is download it as is) because it has too many columns

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting in the JDBC driver, which is documented by the creator of this JDBC driver.
The same question was asked on the [Pentaho forum](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?98546-Increase-the-max-number-of-columns).

Answer (score 0):

The Vortex driver accepts a `max_column` property that I used to fix the very same issue.  Try setting `max_column` to something bigger than 400.

```
Properties dbProps = new Properties();
dbProps.setProperty("max_column", "500");

Connection dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:vortex...", dbProps);
```

In DbVisualizer, when looking at the Connection, go to the Properties tab, and add `max_column` under the Driver Properties section.